# Using the argument principle to calculate a limit of an integral

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, contour-integration

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n \geq 1$. Calculate $$\lim_{R \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz \qquad \text{and }\lim_{R \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{p''(z)}{p(z)}dz.$$

For the first limit this seems quite obvious, since by the argument principle we know that the integral will be equal to the amount of zeros that lie in the circle $|z|=R$. So taking the limit will result in the answer to be $n$. But how would one do the second limit-integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to estimate the modulus of $p''(z)/p(z)$ for large $z$, the argument principle is not needed for the second integral:

It follows from
$$
\frac{p''(z)}{p(z)} = \frac{n(n-1)a_n z^{n-2} + (n-1)(n-2)a_{n-1}z^{n-3} + \cdots }{a_n z^n + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + \cdots}
= \frac{n(n-1)}{z^2} \left( 1 + O\left( \frac 1z\right)\right)
$$
for $z \to \infty$ that
$$
  \oint_{|z|=R} \frac{p''(z)}{p(z)} \, dz = O\left( \frac 1R\right) \, ,
$$
so that the limit for $R \to \infty$ is zero.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without using the 'big-$O$' notation? Like a more direct proof?

Comment: @Geigercounter: It is a natural argument IMO. $p''/p$ converges so fast to zero that the integral over those circles also converges to zero.

Comment: I like this proof, it's pretty slick. However, I'm a bit unsure because it's not as complex analysis-y as I'd expected

Comment: @Geigercounter: The Taylor series of $p''/p$ around $z=\infty$ is of the form $c_2/z^2 + c_3/z^3 + \cdots$, and term-by-term integration also shows that the limit of the integral is zero. That is essentially the same argument, perhaps you find it more satisfying :)

Comment: ah yes beautiful!